# Изменение date в ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Необходимо перевести часы строго на час вперед. Пробовал ntpdate - он синхронизирует, но из-за того, что часы не переводились, то время все так же на час отстает. Т.е., я так думаю, что мне необходимо добавить 3600 секунд, но я не знаю как это правильно сделать.

З.Ы. Нужно осуществить строго через консоль.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo date --set='+1 hour'
```

Comment: Под VirtualBox (ubuntu guest) работает только в данном сеансе. После смены пользователя или перезагрузки опять берет время хоста.

Comment: Так вроде про VirtualBox ничего сказано не было. Был задан вопрос - я ответил. Команда работает, я проверил.

Answer (score 0):

А что мешает на панели нажать на время, перейти в настройки времени и даты, и там сменить? Зачем все усложнять?

Comment: ну программисты же любят =)

чем сис-админы хуже?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, верно :D